# Section list load issue and scrollToLocation issue for Big Data- React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

In My Project, I am using section list with 20 section and each section have more than 10 items.

If I load whole section list once then it will take 10-20 second to load entire screen.

if I used initialNumToRender property and rendered 10 -10 item then it load fast

But at that time ScrollTolocation function not working if I have to scroll on last 6-8 sections
reason for this is my list is not completely render, once whole list render then it work

As per my requirement,I need to show all section on screen. also used can move to any section after opening screen.

Problem arise is if render all section then it will take time to load screen
or if render 10 -10 item then scrolltolocation not working for last section due to rendering not completed

How can I achive both

1. need list to be load fast
2. also scrolltolocation should work for list

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: you can check any sectionlist code with more data , once screen open add button for scroll to last few section, then scroll to location not work and intially list also loading slowly